# How do I convert a localized number to a decimal number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, localization, currency

I have a string in the format `100.000,53` (my country uses points as thousands separator and a comma as the decimal separator). I know about:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
locale.atof('100.000,53')
```

However, this seems to always throw `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100.000.53'`for me (Python 3.6).

Additionally, as money is involved, I want the result to be a decimals number. Can I simply cast the result of `atof` to decimal?